# I have to make a delegate such that when my statusbar gets updated then an event is triggered and the respective text gets displayed

Tags: .net, winforms, delegates, statusbar

I have a project in which status bar gets updated many a times. Now i want to create a delegate such that whenever my status bar gets updated then an event is triggered inside the main form class and respective text gets displayed in the status bar, so that i dont have to create a different StatusLabel.Text for everytime my status bar gets updated. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This description sounds a little convoluted. Are you sure you want a statusbar_updated event to update the status bar? I think this would cause an infinite loop.

I think what you want is an event on your form such that when fired, the status bar is updated. Then all the other code can fire the event when it wants to update the statusbar. The neat thing about this is that if you want logging, you create another subscriber to the event and it works.

Comment: so whats the procedure and syntax like?